# How to handle permissions per role

Tags: permissions, yii2, user-permissions

I am working in a Yii project with 4 or 5 roles. Where each role has access to similar forms and views but do not see all fields. Also there are reports which are only for management level roles.

In the past I have managed permissions based on per field control to avoid repeating code, but this get into a nightmare.

My question is, what is the best approach you have used to handle permissions? per field or per view?

I was thinking in create different views and the admin can select which ones to assign to each role.

Any ideas you can bring will help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use RBAC module http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html

Once you have defined  you role and permission you can use the function provided by Yii2 for show /hide the field you need  or for lead the code behavior

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have used RBAC, but I would like to know your opinion on which approach is better per field or per view?

Comment: I think per field is more advanced usage of RBAC

Comment: I use both  .. and with a good pratice is easy find a fast solution in every situation .. for field there often  parametr like acitive to relate with function like Yii::$app->User->can('your_rule')  and also fo view  you can easily conditioning the behavior with a few check

Comment: @scaisEdge what you are saying is that in same project you use both approaches deppending on the situation? It seems interesting

Comment: I use a pragmatic approach  .. based on some rule .. essentrially i eval the complexity  and for  simple situation is easy use a field approach .. in middle complexity  then i use a  view condition and rendering  .and in complex case i use both inside .. model ... controller ....view and widget .. hope this is useful ..  and all mixed  with object oriented .. extension  ..